# MSBuild: Conditionally run webpack only when there's changes

Tags: visual-studio, webpack, msbuild, visual-studio-2019

We're using Visual Studio 2019 and have successfully configured MSBuild tasks to run webpack for us - both in Debug and Production mode.

But it is a bit overkill to run everytime the project builds e.g. when we run unit tests and there is no changes to the Web project, we don't need webpack to execute.

Is there a way to configure the build task to only execute when files in a particular folder have changed?

Here is our current configuration:

```
<Target Name="DebugRunWebpack" BeforeTargets="Build" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
  <!-- Ensure Node.js is installed -->
  <Exec Command="node --version" ContinueOnError="true">
    <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" PropertyName="ErrorCode" />
  </Exec>
  <Error Condition="'$(ErrorCode)' != '0'" Text="Node.js is required to build and run this project. To continue, please install Node.js from https://nodejs.org/, and then restart your command prompt or IDE." />

  <!-- In development, the dist files won't exist on the first run or when cloning to
       a different machine, so rebuild them if not already present. -->
  <Message Importance="high" Text="Performing first-run Webpack build..." />
  <Exec Command="node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack.config.vendor.js" />
  <Exec Command="node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js" />
</Target>

<Target Name="PublishRunWebpack" AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">
  <!-- As part of publishing, ensure the JS resources are freshly built in production mode -->
  <Exec Command="npm install" />
  <Exec Command="node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack.config.vendor.js --env.prod" />
  <Exec Command="node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --env.prod" />

  <!-- Include the newly-built files in the publish output -->
  <ItemGroup>
    <DistFiles Include="wwwroot\dist\**" />
    <ResolvedFileToPublish Include="@(DistFiles->'%(FullPath)')" Exclude="@(ResolvedFileToPublish)">
      <RelativePath>%(DistFiles.Identity)</RelativePath>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </ResolvedFileToPublish>
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

Comment: Please use this `<Target Name="DebugRunWebpack" BeforeTargets="Build" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' and 'DeployOnBuild'=='true' ">`.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to configure the build task to only execute when files
>   in a particular folder have changed?

You can differentiate the **publish** and **build** process by the `DeployOnBuild` Property.

**Solution**

You only need to add a condition to `DebugRunWebpack` target:

```
<Target Name="DebugRunWebpack" BeforeTargets="Build" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' and 'DeployOnBuild'=='true'">
  <!-- Ensure Node.js is installed -->
......    
</Target>
```

**And** it will only execute the target during publish process.

**In addition**, `PublishRunWebpack` target runs after `ComputeFilesToPublish` which belongs to Publish process. So you do not worry about it.

**Update 1**

To detect whether these files changed, you can try this condition:

`<Target Name="xxxx" Condition="$([System.DateTime]::Parse('%(ModifiedTime)').Ticks) &gt; $([System.IO.File]::GetLastWriteTime('$(xxxxxxxx)%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)').Ticks)" />`

**Note** `$(xxxxxxxx)%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)` means all the files in such folder

**Besides**, you can refer to [this document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19665232/make-an-msbuild-copy-task-only-copy-if-the-source-is-newer-regardless-of-size).

Hope it could help you.

Comment: I'm not trying to differentiate between publish and build processes (perhaps re-read the question). DeployOnBuild is used to create a web deploy package. It doesn't help me configure the build task to only execute when files in a particular folder have changed - specifically, .ts typescript files.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a perfect solution for this. The trick for me was to let MSBuild know about the input files, as well as a specific output file that is generated at every webpack build.

Project.csproj

```
    <!--Webpack configuration-->
    <ItemGroup>
        <WebpackInputs Include="ClientApp\**\*" />
        <WebpackInputs Include=".browserslistrc" />
        <WebpackInputs Include="babel.config.json" />
        <WebpackInputs Include="package.json" />
        <WebpackInputs Include="postcss.config.js" />
        <WebpackInputs Include="webpack.config.js" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <WebpackOutput>wwwroot\dist\build-completed.dat</WebpackOutput>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <!-- Ensures that any changed webpack files trigger a build without using DisableFastUpToDateCheck -->
        <UpToDateCheckInput Include="@(WebpackInputs)" Set="Webpack" />
        <UpToDateCheckOutput Include="$(WebpackOutput)" Set="Webpack" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <Folder Include="ClientApp\" />
        <Folder Include="wwwroot\dist\" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Target Name="PreBuild" BeforeTargets="PreBuildEvent" Inputs="@(WebpackInputs)" Outputs="$(WebpackOutput)">
        <Exec Condition="$(Configuration) == 'Debug'" Command="npm run --silent build-dev" />
        <Exec Condition="$(Configuration) == 'Release'" Command="npm run --silent build-prod" />
    </Target>
    <Target Name="CleanWebpack" AfterTargets="Clean">
        <Message Text="Deleting dist folder from webpack" />
        <RemoveDir Directories="wwwroot\dist" />
    </Target>
```

webpack.config.js

```js
// writes a magic file after build is completed (helps VS with incremental build)
plugins: [{
  apply: (compiler) => {
    compiler.hooks.done.tap("AfterDoneEmitFile", () => {
      var builtFilePath = path.resolve(distPath, "build-completed.dat");
      fs.writeFile(
        builtFilePath,
        new Date(Date.now()).toISOString(),
        () => {}
      );
    });
  },
}]
```